# issue in hiding my data with checkbox

Tags: javascript, css, checkbox

I have two series of data and trying to hide them by clicking on the check box but the data series do not get hidden.

You can see my data series in my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6cJ5c/40/).

And that is the code I have used for hiding them:

**CSS**:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="messageCheckbox" value="line1" onclick="showOrHide(0);" />1
<input type="checkbox" value="line2" checked="checked" class="messageCheckbox" onclick="showOrHide(1);" />2
```

**Javascript**:

```
showOrHide = function (i) {
    var selectt = document.getElementsByClassName("messageCheckbox")[i].value;
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("messageCheckbox")[i].checked) {
        document.getElementsByClassName(selectt)[0].style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        document.getElementsByClassName(selectt)[0].style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to set the attribute `visibility` - http://jsfiddle.net/TrpcW/4/

---

```
<body>
    <div class="line1">data1</div><div class="line2">data2</div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="messageCheckbox" value="line1" onclick="showOrHide(0);" unchecked />1
    <input type="checkbox" value="line2" class="messageCheckbox" onclick="showOrHide(1);" unchecked />2
</body>
```

---

```
showOrHide = function (i) {
    var selectt = document.getElementsByClassName("messageCheckbox")[i].value;
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("messageCheckbox")[i].checked) {
        document.getElementsByClassName(selectt)[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else {
        document.getElementsByClassName(selectt)[0].style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but I want the red graph and blue graph to hide and shown by clinging on the check boxes (check box 1 is for blue one and check box 2 for red one) As you can see I put "line1" and "line2" as the value of checkboxes but that is the error I got: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined "

Comment: here: http://jsfiddle.net/6cJ5c/40/ as you can see I added two input values for checkbox and gave them "line1" and "line2" as the values of check box and at the end of javascript part I added the function of "hideOrShow()" in order to make the red and blue graph invisible and visible but that is the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined "  which is related to hideOrShow function!

Comment: Elements that need to be hidden are within the SVG element. You need to modify `document.getElementsByClassName("messageCheckbox")[i].value` to access the two graphs.

Comment: but how can I do that? :(

Comment: Don't worry it shouldn't be that difficult. You can learn it here - http://svg-whiz.com/svg/HideShow.svg, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/EU1-269j8oo. Good luck :)